# I need to wait for Google Form to finish linked Google sheet data update before executing the Google Form script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I need to wait for Google Form to finish writing data to the linked Google sheet before executing the Google Form script. How can this be done?
I cannot use Utilities.sleep function as it is not a reliable way to ensure it and leads to race condition.

Comment: Have you looked at the `Utilities.sleep` function?

Comment: I think onFormSubmit trigger fires after the data is in the linked sheet.

Comment: I need to wait until the Google Form script finishes. It is not sufficient to wait until the data is in the linked sheet.